# Why does the neural network get stuck when it receives a return from a function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

"I assembled a neural network according to the tutorial, only there is a problem that as input the neural network receives two pictures, one rgb and the other depth, which is stored in dat format, I rewrote the function code and it also takes two pictures only in place of the depth picture in dat, it takes depth in png and it seems to produce the same result as the other one, only when the neural network receives the input from my function, it produces a result that is not similar, although in the two pictures there is the same person, but with the old function it’s the other way around, it produces something that is similar." Here is my function

```
def create_input_rgbd_test_2(image_path, depth_path, show=0):
    # Load color image
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img.thumbnail((640, 480))
    img = np.asarray(img)
    img = img[140:340, 220:420]

    # Load depth image as grayscale
    mat_small = Image.open(depth_path)
    mat_small.thumbnail((640, 480))
    mat_small = np.asarray(mat_small)
    mat_small = mat_small[140:340, 220:420]

    # Normalize depth values
    # mat_small = Image.fromarray(mat_small).convert("L")
    # mat_small = np.asarray(mat_small)
    mat_small = np.mean(mat_small, axis=2)
    mat_small = (mat_small - np.mean(mat_small)) / np.max(mat_small)
    
    # mat_small = np.mean(mat_small, axis=2)

    if show == 1:
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        plt.title('Color Image')
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        plt.title('Normalized Depth Image')
        plt.imshow(mat_small)
        plt.show()

    # Create RGBD image
    full1 = np.zeros((200, 200, 4))
    full1[:, :, :3] = img[:, :, :3]
    full1[:, :, 3] = mat_small

    return np.array([full1])
```

Here's a function another function

```
def create_input_rgbd(file_path, show=0):
    # print(file_path)
    mat=np.zeros((480,640), dtype='float32')
    i=0
    j=0
    depth_file = file_path
    with open(depth_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            vals = line.split('\t')
            for val in vals:
                if val == "\n": continue    
                if int(val) > 1200 or int(val) == -1: val= 1200
                mat[i][j]=float(int(val))
                j+=1
                j=j%640

            i+=1
        mat = np.asarray(mat)
    mat_small=mat[140:340,220:420]
    img = Image.open(depth_file[:-5] + "c.bmp")
    img.thumbnail((640,480))
    img = np.asarray(img)
    img = img[140:340,220:420]
    mat_small=(mat_small-np.mean(mat_small))/np.max(mat_small)

    if show == 1:
        plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.imshow(mat_small)
        plt.show()
        plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()    
    
    
    
    full1 = np.zeros((200,200,4))
    full1[:,:,:3] = img[:,:,:3]
    full1[:,:,3] = mat_small
    
    return np.array([full1])
```

[Here is a link to the neuron and a couple of depth dat files and also in png and also the scales of the neuron](https://github.com/GHOSTxxx123/FaceAI/)

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)